# Mathematical problem

Tags: math

Here is the problem:

One sheet contains 10 labels.  I want to print many labels, but from an arbitrary starting index.  Now, I want to find how many sheets would be required to print the labels that the user desires.  For example, let's say I took starting index 52 and I want to print 23 labels.  Then how do I find the number of sheets required?  Does anyone have a formula to count this?

*edit* Hello guys, thanks for the answers the problem is solved now.
thank u very much all.

Comment: You need to give a better example, as the relation between the starting index and the number of labels isn't apparent.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Does your label index start at 0 or 1?

Comment: @Bill I'm assuming 1, as he is starting at index 10, with 10 per page

Comment: Having a clarity in question helps to have good solution. It would be good if you can rephrase it a better.

Comment: Why would you need 7 sheets to print 52 labels? Do you want to leave nine labels blank on the first page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean that you have a predetermined page layout, i.e. if you want to print labels 42 to 67, you have to print the pages with the labels 40-49, 50-59, and 60-69.

All you need to do is find the sheet index of the starting page and the sheet index of the ending page, subtract them, and add 1.  The sheet index of label *n* is floor(n/10) (or just n/10 with integer division).  So, if your starting label is *n*, and you want to print *x* labels, the number of sheets you need is:

```
floor((n+x)/10) - floor(n/10) + 1
```

This all assumes zero-based indices, for sanity (that means that the first label has index 0).  If your label numbers are one-based, i.e. the first label has the index 1, then you need to subtract one from *n* first, so the formula becomes:

```
floor((n-1+x)/10) - floor((n-1)/10) + 1
```

This should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Ceil((52-10)/10)

### code example

In Delphi this would be

```
function AmountOfSheets(startingIndex: Integer; labels: Integer): Integer;
const
  ILabelsPerSheet: Integer = 10;    
begin
  Result := Ceil((labels - startingIndex) / ILabelsPerSheet);
end;
```

Thanks to everyone who commented on getting it right, or to quote jc *with a little help from my friends*.

Comment: I've interpreted "starting index" to be the first label position to use on the first page, which your code wouldn't account for...

Comment: This code will produce an extra sheet if (labels - startingIndex) is wholly divisible by ILabelsPerSheet. You need to use the ceiling function like Pop Catalin's answer

Comment: Rowland & Mark, you are both right offcourse. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> for example i took starting index 10
>   and i want to print 52 labels.then how
>   i find the no of sheets required

Ceiling( ( 52 - 10 + 1 ) / 10 ) -> pages (Edit: make sure you perform floating point division instead of integer)

( 52 - 10 + 1 ) % 10   -> number of labels on last page

Comment: Actually, you needn't use floating point division; for positive integers, Ceil((float)x/y) is written in integer arithmetic as (x+y-1)/y

Comment: @jpalecek, you are right, that trick gave me a flashback from math classes in high school, I remember my math teacher teaching us that trick :), Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The number of pages required is (using integer arithmetics):

```
(items + pageSize - 1) / pageSize
```

where `items` is the number of labels to print and `pageSize` is the number of labels per page.

The starting index is irrelevant for the number of pages as long as you know how many labels you are going to print. If you print 25 labels it doesn't matter if the starting index is 4 or 827364827364, it's still 25 labels.

---

Edit:

If you want to use the index to optionally leave labels blank on the first page, i.e. print 19 labels from index 14 to index 32:

```
Page 1: -- -- -- 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
Page 2: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
Page 3: 31 32 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Then you first calculate how many labels to leave blank before the first label:

```
(index - 1) % pageSize
```

(where % is the modulus (or remainder) operator.)

Then you add these empty items to the number of labels to calculate the actual number of items to print. For the example above it would be 3 + 19 = 22. This would then be used in the calculation above to get the number of pages.

Comment: but if take starting index 10 and i want to print 52 labels then it's answer shoul be 7(no of sheets) which is i am not getting in your formula

Comment: 52 labels takes 6 sheets. There must be some confusion as to what the index is used for

Answer (score 1):

The number of sheets required will always be the total you want to do divided by 10, rounded up. If the starting index takes away from the total to be printed it will be the total labels negative the starting index divided by 10, rounded up.

ceil ( Total Labels / 10 )

ceil ( (Total Labels - Index) / 10 )

**A PHP example:**

```
$starting_index=0;
$total=52 - $starting_index;
$labels_per_page=10;
$pages=ceil($total / $labels_per_page);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the intention is to reuse half used sheets of labels you've got something like

```
labelsOnFirstPage = labelsPerPage + 1 - StartIndex
if( totalLabels > labelsOnFirstPage )
{
    return 1 + Ceiling( (totalLabels - labelsOnFirstPage) / labelsPerPage )
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your very-hard-to-understand question that your "starting index" is a position on the page where the first label will be printed. Something like this:

```
1     2
3     4
5     6
7     8
9     10
```

So then the number of pages you print is the total number of labels you want, minus the labels you print on the first page, divided by the number of labels per page:

```
int labels_per_page = 10;
int starting_index = 10;
int total_labels = 52;
// Edit to account for a starting_index of more than labels_per_page:
int first_page = labels_per_page - ((starting_index - 1) % labels_per_page);
// first_page has one label
int remaining_labels =  total_labels - first_page;
if (remaining_labels <= 0) { return 1; }
// 51 labels left
int total_pages = ceiling(remaining_labels / labels_per_page) + 1;
// 7 pages total
return total_pages;
```

You'll need to make sure that `first_page` is greater than `total_labels` since there might only be one page.

Comment: what if i take starting index 25 than the result of first page will be negative

Comment: Then take the modulus of it in the size of the page. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the same interpretation as Svante, with indices starting at 1, I would write the answer as

```
nSheets = ceiling((startIndex+nLabels) / 10) - ceiling(startIndex / 10) + 1
```

For the example given, with 52 labels starting from index 10, we have labels numbered until index 61 (=10+52-1):

```
                           10 (end of first sheet -> 1 label)
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 (second sheet -> 11 labels)
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 (third sheet -> 21 labels)
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 (fourth sheet -> 31 labels)
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 (fifth sheet -> 41 labels)
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 (sixth sheet -> 51 labels)
61                            (beginning of seventh sheet -> 52 labels)
```

so that **7** sheets are needed, and we can check

```
ceiling((10+52)/10)-ceiling(10/10)+1 = ceiling(6.2)-ceiling(1)+1 = 7-1+1 = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

⌈(52-10+1)/10⌉

Comment: ⌈(52-10+1)/10⌉ = ⌈(43)/10⌉ = ⌈4.3⌉ = 5

DONE!

Comment: u cant understand my problem dear what if i took starting index 55 and want to print 5 labels.then how could u count no of sheets?